# Can you load a tree structure in memory with Linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to create an application with a Linux shell script like this — but can it be done?

This application will create a tree containing data. The tree should be loaded in the memory. The tree (loaded in memory) could be readable from any other external Linux script.

- Is it possible to do it with a Linux shell?
- If yes, how can you do it?
- And are there any simple examples for that?

Comment: could you explain why -1.  my question is not clear?

Comment: There are a large number of misconceptions on display in the question.  Each process normally has its own memory; there's no trivial way to load 'the tree' into one process's memory and make it available to all other processes.  You might devise a system of related programs that know about a shared memory segment somehow that contains the tree, but that's about it.  What you're seeking is simply not available in the shell.  That's probably why someone else down-voted your question.

Comment: so this could be a response to my question because I already said in my question `Is it possible to do it with a Linux shell?`. such question could interest newbie shell programmer that they have the same problem I have.

Comment: An OK question, even in its original form. Answerable - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a related discussion here. They use shared memory device **/dev/shm** and, ostensibly, it works for multiple users. At least, it's worth a try:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/bash-is-it-possible-to-write-to-memory-rather-than-a-file-671891/

Edit: just tried it with two users on Ubuntu - looks like a normal directory and **REALLY WORKS** with the right chmod.

See also:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html

Answer (score 2):

There are a large number of misconceptions on display in the question.

Each process normally has its own memory; there's no trivial way to load 'the tree' into one process's memory and make it available to all other processes. You might devise a system of related programs that know about a shared memory segment (somehow — there's a problem right there) that contains the tree, but that's about it.  They'd be special programs, not general shell scripts.  That doesn't meet your 'any other external Linux script' requirement.

What you're seeking is simply not available in the Linux shell infrastructure.  That answers your first question; the other two are moot given the answer to the first.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do this as if you want to keep all the requirements of:

- Building this as a shell script
- In-memory
- Usable across terminals / from external scripts

You would have to give up at least one requirement:

1. Give up shell script req - Build this in C to run as a Linux process. I only understand this up to the point to say that it would be non-trivial
2. Give up in-memory req - You can serialize the tree and keep the data in a temp file. This works as long as the file is small and performance bottleneck isn't around access to the tree. The good news is you can use the data across terminals / from external scripts
3. Give up usability from external scripts req - You can technically build a script and run it by sourcing it to add many (read: a mess of) variables representing the tree into your current shell session.

None of these alternatives are great, but if you had to go with one, number 2 is probably the least problematic.